# Measuring I/O Performance Paradox

Tags: performance-tuning, performance, nfs

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to get the *'real world'* write performance
of my NFS cluster.

The NFS export is mount on a XEN hypervisor, and I'm running *'dd'* from within a VM.

**What** I can't decide is should I use `O_DIRECT/O_SYNC` or not.

If I won't use it, the kernel will do page caching to RAM, and I'll will end up measuring
RAM throughput, not disk.

On the other hand, most if not all server applications will use RAM caching anyway(am I wrong with that assumption?).

So I wonder where is the balance point, what will really happen in the *'real world'*?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd use an actual I/O benchmark utility such as 'iozone'. It'll test a variety of things and will even use O_DIRECT if flagged to do so. And even, as I recall, has some NFS-specific flags.

One thing I've found to be very reliable is to use a file-size that exceeds the RAM size for the device you're testing on. This busts the cache, and gives you reliable I/O numbers. If you have a 2GB RAM machine and test on a 4GB file, you'll get reliable numbers. If you use a 1GB file, but use the O_DIRECT flag instead, you'll get somewhat different numbers due to the 'only report comitted when told it is flushed' aspect of O_DIRECT.

This gets complicated when your network-file-system target also has a block-cache, so you may need to size your test to bust *that* cache rather than your Xen-local cache.

Answer (score 2):

This only depend about what you want to measure.
You just forgot to define your goal.

If you want the NFS cluster raw performances, then you have to bypass your RAM.
If you want "real world" performances, then you have to use your RAM. But real world I/O are rarely those from dd. You will have better results with iozone for example.

So define your goal.
Then choose the appropriate tool and method.